# Can I filter/hide closed questions on Programmers.SE?

Tags: support, search, filtering

This might be better suited for Meta.SO, but the problem is particularly bad here, so that's where I'm asking.

Of the active questions on the Programmers home page, 7 are closed and another 2 are in negative voting territory. This is a given as the scope of Programmers is much tighter than the other sites. But it's a pain to navigate. Is there any way to filter the questions so that only open questions are visible?

Comment: I know there are a lot of questions on the closing of questions here, but this is specifically about making P.SE easier to navigate, not about the moderation policy per se.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a custom filtered view of questions?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/how-can-i-create-a-custom-filtered-view-of-questions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no preference setting to show or hide closed questions, but you can bookmark a search:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=closed%3a0

This shows you the open question sorted in the descending order by recent activity. See more search tips [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search).

Comment: I would *really* like a user account preference. I'm on here to help, not so much to get answers. And there are **many** closed questions here specifically. The related questions when composing a question should be unfilterable though, to see the duplicates and click on them instead of finishing the question.